# Golang net/http Backend blocking requests

Tags: go, backend

Is there an way to reject/block an request in go net/http "listenandserver"?
In my case I want that only requests with useragent "test 1.0" are allowed. Everything else will be blocked.
"I also want to make an rate limit. ex: (If requests per second from same IP gets over 50 R/S over second block for 1h...)" I can do this but as I said I dont know how to block the request.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.UserAgent() == "test/1.0" {
        //Allow
    } else {
        //Block request
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handle)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options.  The first is to return an [error](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Error) response:

```
func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.UserAgent() == "test/1.0" {
        //Allow
    } else {
        http.Error(w, "forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }
}
```

The second is to [hijack](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Hijacker) the the connection from the server and rudely close the connection:

```
func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.UserAgent() == "test/1.0" {
        //Allow
    } else {
        if h, ok := w.(http.Hijacker); ok {
            c, _, err := h.Hijack()
            if err != nil {
                c.Close()
                return
            }
        }
        // fallback to error response
        http.Error(w, "forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }
}
```